# flask dropbox quick start example with openshift

Tags: python, flask, openshift, dropbox-api

I'm not able to successfully execute an example from http://flask-dance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstarts/dropbox.html on the openshift platform.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask_dance.contrib.dropbox import make_dropbox_blueprint, dropbox

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "supersekrit"
blueprint = make_dropbox_blueprint(
    app_key="my-key-here",
    app_secret="my-secret-here",
)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not dropbox.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("dropbox.login"))
    resp = dropbox.get("account/info")
    assert resp.ok
    return "You are {email} on Dropbox".format(email=resp.json()["email"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I'm getting either a transport error (openshift tries to use HTTP uri instead of HTTPS), or if I try to set

> os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

(which I know is not recommended for security) then I get

> InvalidClientIdError: (invalid_request) Can't use "Authorization"
>   header and "client_secret" arg together.

both locally and on the openshift platform.

Any suggestion on what to tweak in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting either a transport error (openshift tries to use HTTP uri
>   instead of HTTPS)

Try accessing the index on `https://yourApp-namespace.rhcloud.com` (not http) and make sure it is configured for your Dropbox app as one of the redirect URIs.

If that won't work, you may take a look on [this](http://flask-dance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/proxies.html). However, the tutorial code works for me with [the flask quick-start](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-base) that's offered on OpenShift. Only the app config must be referenced in the `flaskapp.py` (i.e. `app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')`), additionally to the code you've linked and posted above.

Comment: The ProxyFix reference was very helpful as openshift does run plain HTTP behind a TLS router.. with  app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app) I got the dropbox oath code to work based on their [guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/datastore/tutorial/python).

Answer (score 1):

Did you get familiar on how you can deploy basic flask app on openshift. Here is a link to the official openshift documents https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html and here https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-base. Once you got your openshift flask-base app up and running then you can enhance it with adding the additional dropbox module through virtualenv. When you successful deploy the app from the openshift example and it runs, then extend it with the additional Flask-Dance by putting the dependency in the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='FlaskApp',
  version='1.0',
  description='A basic Flask app with static files',
  author='Ryan Jarvinen',
  author_email='ryanj@redhat.com',
  url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
 install_requires=['Flask>=0.10.1','Flask-Dance'],
 )
```

and then use it in the flaskapp.py as it it done on the example from your dropbox guide http://flask-dance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstarts/dropbox.html.

Comment: I'm able to deploy flask to openshift and even excecute dropbox API calls by manually authorizing the access (per https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/python). But I have trouble executing the oauth "dance" as in the flask-dropbox example.  Are you able to run the code I posted without errors?